# Silverstripe 3 - foreach loop to return multiple objects

Tags: php, foreach, silverstripe

I've got an ItemObject with the field 'Categories'. In this field, the IDs of the related CategoryPages are stored as string. e.g 25,30,8.

Now I want to return only the ItemObjects, where the CategoryPage ID is in the string of the Categories Field.

To achieve this, I created this function

```
public function getItemsForCategory() {
    $items = Item::get();
    foreach($items as $item) {
        $categories = $item->Categories;
        $explode = explode(',', $categories);
        if( in_array($this->ID, $explode) ) {
            echo $item->ID . '<br>';
        }
    }   
}
```

It puts the correct IDs of the ItemObject for this one Category in the Page. So it works, but I want to return the ItemObjects for the Category so I replaced the `echo $item->ID ...;` with `return $item;` but it seems that this is only returning the first Item for the Category.

Can someone please tell me my mistake?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why would you save the IDs as string? Storing them using a has_many or many_many relation would be easier for you as developer, probably also also easier for the CMS user, more reliable, more performant and more maintainable.

Comment: I thought that was the fastest way. You can assign a category via CheckboxSetField. To store it with a $many_many relation, I need to create a extra DataObject for that?

But anyways. Why isn't my code working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will answer your question, why your code is not working,
However, I must warn you, this code is **bad** and I **strongly advise against** using **it**!

What you need to understand is how functions work.
A key rule of a function is that "return" means the end of a function. A return statement means that there will be no more code executed in this function, its the end.
So that's the reason why its not working.

To get it working like this, you need to create an array/list to store the items you want to return.

```
public function getItemsForCategory() {
    // DO NOT USE - I ADVISE AGAINST USING THIS! THERE IS A MUCH BETTER WAY TO HANDLE IT!
    $matchingItems = ArrayList::create();
    $items = Item::get();
    foreach($items as $item) {
        $ids = explode(',', $item->Categories);
        if(in_array($this->ID, $explode)) {
            $matchingItems->add($item);
        }
    }
    return $matchingItems;
}
```

---

**Doing it the right way:**

Again, I strongly urge against using the above example.
See the example below for doing it right:

SilverStripe comes with a ORM and a DataModel capable of managing 1...n (has_many) and n...m (many_many) relations.
And some of the FormFields, including `CheckboxSetField` can save into those relations.
The example contains 2 ways to handle relations, a `GridField` and a `CheckboxSetField`:

```
class CategoryPage extends Page {
    // in template you can then do <% if $Items %> and <% loop $Items %>
    private static $many_many = array(
        'Items' => 'Item',
    );
    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root', Tab::create('Items', 'The Items');
        $config = GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor::create();
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.items', GridField::create(
            'Items',
            'Items for this Category',
            $this->Items(),
            $config
        ));
        return $fields;
    }
}

class Item extends DataObject {
    // in template you can do <% if $Categories %> and <% loop $Categories %>
    private static $belongs_many_many = array(
        'Categories' => 'CategoryPage',
    );
    public function getCMSFields() {
        $map = CategoryPage::get()->map();
        return FieldList::create(array(
            TextField::create('Title', 'Item Name'),
            CheckboxSetField::create('Categories', 'Categories for this Item', $map),
        ));
    }
}
```

This code will store the relation in a relational db.
SilverStripe will magically create methods for the relation:

```
$categoriesForItem = $item->Categories();
```

and:

```
$items= $category->Items();
```

Comment: thank you very much. I won't use it but it's good to know why it doesn't work. But can you also tell me why it's bad?

Comment: 1) you should never store more than 1 value in 1 field. There is a set of rules/guidlines for designing a database: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization (German Version: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: 2) the method you used would fetch ALL Items from the database, and then loop it. which is bad for performance. When you use many_many, and then call `$category->Items();`, it will only get the items it needs (it does the filtering in a database level using `WHERE ID = IN (....)`)

Comment: 3) you can not filter the database for the IDs, and you can not use joins.